# How can I control the slash in Url Action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm on working an Asp.net MVC project that I have use an URL like that:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Privacy")#Legal" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

Which I want it go to: `/Privacy/Index#Legal`
But it auto added the slash which make the URL not good: `/Privacy/Index#/Legal`

What I'm wrong? Sorry I'm a new Asp.net MVC developer. Thanks

**UPDATED:**
I found the problem that my project used AngularJS, the solution that config the $locationPrivider will solve the problem:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
    rewriteLinks: false
});
```

Thanks for all your support.

Comment: why don't you just provide the url to href?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I also use the normal URL but it also have problem.

Comment: what problem? you are just providing the correct url.

Comment: The problem was that I want it go to the "Legal" section on the page. If the url correct is "/Privacy/Index#Legal" it wil work. If the URL is "/Privacy/Index#/Legal" it won't work.

Comment: <a href = "/Privacy/Index#Legal">Terms and condition</a>. Whats the problem with this?

Comment: Thank you @RachitGupta, The problem was it will add the additional slash before Legal "Privacy/Index#/Legal" and it will not go to Legal section of Index page

Comment: what will add additional slash. If you don't use Url.Action, it will redirect to correct page.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure whether or not to use trailing slash in urls throug `AppendTrailingSlash` property of `RouteCollection` object.
In order to remove it from all URLs in your application you should modify `RegisterRoutes` method

```
public class RouteConfig
 {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            ///add this line
            routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
        }
 }
```

Once you set this up `@Url.Action("Index","Privacy")` will be generated without  trailing slash